# Set Bold font in first row of excel file using core php

Tags: php

I want to set bold font and change background color of first row in excel file without using PHPExcel.Is that any way to do it? 
I want to do it by using simple core php.

Comment: How are you reading/writing this "excel file" at the moment? Is it a real BIFF- or OfficeOpenXML format Excel file, or simply a csv file or html markup?

Comment: And if you want to do it without using PHPExcel, then you'll either need to use another library, or send a few man-years writing your own; because handling Excel format files is non-trivial

Comment: PS. PHPExcel is written in simple core PHP

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
i am writing file as describe in link:-
http://www.lateralcode.com/excel-spreadsheets-php/
It is so simple and easy.

Comment: Yes, it's simple and easy, because it isn't an Excel file, it's a csv file..... and csv files cannot support formatting of any kind; you cannot set colour or font styling in a csv file, so what you are asking is really not possible unless you write a native format spreadsheet file..... you can try using html markup instead of csv, but some versions of Excel will object to your doing that

Comment: okay Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate excel file from php, just create a html table structure and echo out this html. In html you can easily customize table's first row. But before echo don't forget to add headers in php script like -

```
<?php
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file1.xls");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
?>
```

Comment: Yes you are right,
i had tried that but i got <b>Abc</b> such king of output